# Barplot of variables by factors

Tags: r, graph, plot

I wish to plot barplots for different categories (V, C and S in the dummy data) for values of different variables (v1-v5) to see how ranges of the different categories vary across the variable. Is there a way to do it in R ?

```
 Factor   v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
      v 12.0 8.4 5.3 3.0 3.5
      v 11.8 7.5 4.7 2.8 3.7
      c 13.2 9.5 5.7 3.0 4.1
      c 13.4 9.3 6.3 3.3 3.8
      c 10.5 7.7 5.0 2.5 3.2
      s 13.1 9.6 5.4 3.1 3.9
      s 15.0 9.0 5.1 4.5 9.0
```

Its should be a very simple code using some package, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns("^v"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Factor, y=value1)) +
  stat_summary(aes(fill=variable), fun.y="sum", geom = "bar", position="dodge") +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:

[image]

Used data:

```
df <- read.table(text="Factor   v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
v 12.0 8.4 5.3 3.0 3.5
v 11.8 7.5 4.7 2.8 3.7
c 13.2 9.5 5.7 3.0 4.1
c 13.4 9.3 6.3 3.3 3.8
c 10.5 7.7 5.0 2.5 3.2
s 13.1 9.6 5.4 3.1 3.9
s 15.0 9.0 5.1 4.5 9.0", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Does theme_bw() necessary? It depends on the user interest, isn't it?

Comment: @CristianVelandia It's indeed not necessary, but I like it more than the gey background.

Comment: @Jaap Nice solution. However, when transforming the data from wide to long with melt the name of the column is value1 instead of value, so I have to change the name inside ggplot: `y = value1`. Am I doing something wrong or it is a typo?

Comment: @mpalanco True, I changed the answer. This is due to a minor bug in data.table. In the development version (which I'm using) this is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to achieve this task

```
df<- read.csv("dummy.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
df
class(df)
df2<-aggregate(cbind(df$v1,df$v2,df$v3,df$v4,df$v5)~df$Factor, FUN=sum)
df2

barp<-barplot(t(df2[ , -1]),col=c("blue", "red", "green", "orange", "gold"));
axis(side = 1, at = barp, labels = df2$`df$Factor`)
```

Comment: data used here is the same you are using